# Get the content of div within div using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to get the content of a div with a class of "**gt-read**" and within the div have another div that has a different class. Below is the script code snippet:

**Scripts :**

```
data = """
    <div class='gt-read'>
        <!-- no need -->
        <!-- some no need -->

        <b>Bold text</b> - some text here <br/>
        lorem ipsum here <br/>
        <strong> Author Name</strong>

        <div class='some-class'>
            <script>
                #...
                Js script here
                #...
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
    """
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
get_class = soup.find("div", {"class" : "detail_text"})
print 'notices', notices.get_text()
print 'notices', notices
```

and I want results like this:

```
<b>Bold text</b> - some text here <br/>
lorem ipsum here <br/>
<strong> Author Name</strong>
```

Kindly help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should display what you need:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment  

data = """
    <div class='gt-read'>
        <!-- no need -->
        <!-- some no need -->

        <b>Bold text</b> - some text here <br/>
        lorem ipsum here <br/>
        <strong> Author Name</strong>

        <div class='some-class'>
            <script>
                #...
                Js script here
                #...
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
    """
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
get_class = soup.find("div", {"class" : "gt-read"})
comments = get_class.find_all(text=lambda text:isinstance(text, Comment))
[comment.extract() for comment in comments]

get_class.find("div").extract()
text = get_class.encode_contents().strip()

print text
```

Giving you the following output:

```
<b>Bold text</b> - some text here <br/>
        lorem ipsum here <br/>
<strong> Author Name</strong>
```

This gets the `gt-read` class, extracts all comments and the div tag, and returns the remaining markup.

Comment: This is work from my case, thanks. this very helpful !